# Flow inheritance results in incompatible type at runtime

Tags: javascript, inheritance, types, casting, flowtype

A.js:

```
// @flow
export interface A {
  propA: string;
  method(): void;
}
```

B.js:

```
// @flow
import { A } from "../interfaces/A.js";
export class B implements A {
  propA: string;
  // Additional properties here...

  method() { //do stuff }
  // Additional methods here...
};
```

main.js:

```
// @flow
import { A } from "../interfaces/A.js";
import { B } from "../classes/B.js";

export const processA = (w: string, obj: A): string => {
  return processB(w, obj);
};

const processB = (_w: string, _obj: B): string => {
  return _w;
};
```

Error: `Cannot call 'processB' with 'obj' bound to '_obj' because 'A' [1] is incompatible with 'B' [2].`

(Yes I know the A/B obj are not used in these functions, this is just a trimmed down example)

I understand why the error is being thrown, because in `processB` there is no guarantee that input `_obj` is of type `B` since it is of type `A`. But I'd like to have a method that takes in an `obj: A` and then passes to a submethod that requires `obj` to be of type `B`.

Is there a way to accomplish this? I'm kind of hacking around it by manually checking the `constructor.name` and using `instanceof` before calling `processB`, and changing declaration to `const processB = (_w: string, _obj: A)`.

But it seems like there could be a better way. I want the initial method to take in any object that implements the interface, then have submethods that enforce the input obj to be a certain class that extends that interface.

Answer (score 0):

I could only think of using `instanceof` since Flow needs some way of guaranteeing what type `obj` is. You don't need to change `processB` to accept an `A` if you're using `instanceof`, however. For example,

```
interface A {
  propA: string;
  method(): void;
};

class B implements A {
  propA: string;
  // Additional properties here...
  propB: string;

  method() { 
    // do stuff
  }
  // Additional methods here...
}

class C implements A {
  propA: string;
  // Additional properties here...
  propC: string;

  method() {
    // do stuff
  }
  // Additional methods here...
}

function processA(w: string, obj: A): string {
  if (obj instanceof B) {
    return processB(w, obj);
  } else if (obj instanceof C) {
    return processC(w, obj);
  }

  throw new Error('Unsupported implementation of interface A');
  // or just return a default string
};

function processB(w: string, obj: B): string {
  return w + obj.propB;
};

function processC(w: string, obj: C): string {
  return w + obj.propC;
}
```

[Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4ChnIA5QD2eqAXMgM5hSgDmA3DsgLYRgAWhAJgBQCU5AG6FgXRgF9GWBABs4FCsgBCyYMzwyIrcIvTZcBYmUrU6jXAHoLaLl2BhghEHBn4ieaA4iL20CADpApkM8JXIqGhAGLCZWDm5+TGQmS2suQhMAVxgYJnEmKxs7BycXFjZOLh8-QP8sfOk5BWQAYVV1TW0wXUxg92MIswLrVFt7R2dXEM9gb2RfKACgg3cW8NMoqVw4ysT9XGRC9KycvOGi8dLXHe5qxdr6mJhMkAQSkDdCJAVUHgB3daRWgAGmQhAARgArcioAQmIG9XDAGDIHgQyGqEBUOCvCCEFFKPiI5AASEWYEyUA+hm+FCU-1B6L45mQ4mQEBkFBQyNR6Mx2Nx+NaRP2uHJlOpRFpLQZYKhzLOuCYHCIf2QIAgaoAolAiFAeAByACqWMyeDwhCgkC47Q0Wgg4Dg7zBKNAkFgiBQqANCtSYKgyEhmSoyHFVOQcGQXAg8EyMjA8Lo9Skz1ezpp3jp-0BdEZUPIhJzUWJYY+aoA1HLIf4QkoJCmXm8Jp9pdnE1E89DhUXaCW2BLkBWqzXVhIgA)